# Laravel error Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist'

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5, illuminate-container

When I wanted to add form in my laravel 5.2 project I got some errors in composer.
After that My whole project got a strange error bellow :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(738):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Kernel') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(230):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(735):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container{closure}(Object(Illuminate
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gifkadeh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 738

Comment: Check if the `app\Http\Kernel.php` file exists.

Comment: yes it exists and has no problem

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpauto -o`. If it doesn't help, try to manually delete autoload files and run this command again.

Comment: show us the kernel file

Comment: after deleting autoload files I have new error :  Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\laravel\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes dependencies are incompatible or have some bugs.
You can try to:

1. restore your old composer.lock file
2. delete vendor folder
3. execute 'composer install'